# How do I insert emojis into a nickname in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Every time I try to do that, the emoji just changes into a question mark. Here's my code:

```js
client.on("message", async (msg) => {
    if (msg.content == "*verify check") {
        msg.member.setNickname(`${msg.member.displayName} ✅`);
        message.react(`✅`);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: [I tried reproducing your code](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/722174152357707776/765739608499027978/unknown.png) and it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: So i ended up switching to VS Code from Community 2019, and it works! It's uncanny! Thank you guys for the helpful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message variable in the above code is inconsistent. You used 'msg' to catch the return value but used 'message' to react. Keep it consistent, otherwise, you might face errors. Also, a bot cannot change the nickname of the owner of the server, so if you want to test this code, make sure you are not the owner of the server where you are testing it.

```
bot.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content == "*verify check") {
        message.member.setNickname(`${message.member.displayName} ✅`)
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
        message.react(`✅`);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the improved example. It finally worked after two days of torture haha